# Does anyone have a working IPython kernel for node.js?

Tags: node.js, ipython

I tried [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Carreau/4279371/node-kernel.ipynb), but it's not working.

ZeroMQ finally installed with a lot of frustration on OS X. Note I had to do:

```
npm install zmq
```

In my home directory for the `kernel.js` file to find it with `require()`.

I had to modify `ipython_config.py` with

```
c.KernelManager.kernel_cmd = ["/usr/local/bin/node", "~/node-kernel/kernel.js", "{connection_file}"]

c.Session.key = b''
c.Session.keyfile = b''
```

I just get a bunch of stuff spewed onto the screen from this section of `kernel.js`:

```
reply_socket.on('message',
        function(data){
            for(i in arguments){
               console.log("[" + i + "]: " + arguments[i].toString());
            }
```